# Why do we pass objects as arguments in java?

Tags: java, object, parameters, arguments

```
Box mybox = new Box(1,2);
Box mybox2 = new Box(mybox);
```

I know how to pass objects as arguments but i need to know what is their use in programming.

How is it useful?

Please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Box mybox2 = new Box(mybox);` is essentially a copy constructor.

In your constructor you would be ideally copying properties of myBox into myBox2.

Few benefits:

- an alternative to clone method
- simply extract the argument's data, and could be forwarded to the
  regular constructor
- could be used with immutable objects
- when you have objects with many properties and would want to copy them

Also a good read : [Josh Bloch on Design](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

Comment: hi aNish, i know that. But i want to know why do we do it? For example, a constructor is used to initialize variables. i need an answer like that. What is the reason for passing objects as arguments?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much just used to duplicate the object. It may be used in a trial and error way, or like a save state.

Take Notepad for example, you save a document with 5 words, and you write 5 more words in it. It's pretty much duplicated itself and added 5 words.

It seems really hard to explain.

You can alter the duplicate box without changing the original, if that makes sense.

Hope it helped.

Jarod.

Comment: Thanks, i understood a little bit. But still confused though. I mean, when you can simple pass variables or used input, why do you need to pass objects as variables?

Comment: Simplicities sake I guess... For example, Rectangles:

`Rectangle()` - `Rectangle(int width, int height)` - `Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)` - `Rectangle(Rectangle r)`

You can either have a blank rectangle, a rectangle at 0,0 with width and height, a rectangle at x, y, with width and height, or a rectangle copied across from the original...

So instead of typing in x, y, width, height, all the time, you can just write, rect.

I'm sorry, I'm still pretty confusing. :P

Answer (score 0):

Thats a really broad question ;) Try to think of `Objects` in a simpler way:

Objects in programming are like objects in the real world. Like a "door" for example. A door is an object and that object has certain properties. For example it could be made of wood and it could have the color blue. Then this door can have other objects attached to it. Like the "door knob" for example. In Java this could look like this:

```
public class Door{
   String color;
   String material;
   Knob doorKnob;

   public Door(String color, String material, Knob doorKnob){
      this.color = color;
      this.material = material;
      this.doorKnob = doorKnob;
   }
}


public class Knob{

   String material;

   public Knob(String material){
        this.material = material;
   }
}

// then when you want to create your door you first have to get a doorknob
 .... 
 Knob myDoorKnob = new Knob("chrome");

 Door myDoor = new Door("blue", "wood", myDoorKnob);
```

And there you have it. Your door needs another object – the door knob. So in your example you pass a `Box` Object to another `Box` object, probably like the others said to copy the boxes properties into the new box:

```
public class Box{
   String content;

   public Box(Box that){
     this.content = that.getContent();
   }

   public String getContent(){
     return this.content;
   }
}
```

Comment: Woah, thanks man. A clear answer. wow, now i have understood this concept.